# Conflicting Packages in React Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Just looking to resolve this. I'm quite sure it'll be an easy solve for people used to node packaging errors.

I'm trying to resolve:  npm install @material-ui/icons

When using, I receive the following:

---

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/material@5.2.3
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.6.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.2.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         @mui/material@"^5.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.2.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"^5.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   11 more (@emotion/styled, @testing-library/react, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/material@5.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"^5.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/material@5.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     @mui/material@"^5.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

---

I've worked back to my yarn.lock package, which has the following. One note, I am not using yarn.

---

```
"react@*", "react@^17.0.2", "react@>= 16", "react@>= 16.8.0", "react@>=16.6.0", "react@>=16.8.0", "react@17.0.2":
"integrity" "sha512-gnhPt75i/dq/z3/6q/0asP78D0u592D5L1pd7M8P+dck6Fu/jJeL6iVVK23fptSUZj8Vjf++7wXA8UNclGQcbA=="
"resolved" "https://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-17.0.2.tgz"
"version" "17.0.2"
dependencies:
    "loose-envify" "^1.1.0"
    "object-assign" "^4.1.1"
```

---

It's likely also worth noting my package.json is:

---

```
{
"name": "new",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
    ]
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
    ]
}
}
```

---